# How to show an embedded video inside of a window in C# WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, embedded-resource

**What I need :**

In C# WPF on Visual studio 2019 in Windows 10, I want to show and play a video inside a My window from the app not directly path

**What have I done** :

I have included that video in my project, then I set the path for the video and it shows it to me in design view! :
[image]

but when I start my project , It won't show the video !
[image]

**What have I tried and my code :**

so I decided to try it in three-way, also to try to show a gif for sure about the path.

1. Embedded path
2. Normal Path
3. Direct path on windows

but only the direct path works! While the same embedded path works for GIF

*MyGIF* : `Source="pack://application:,,,/Medias/1Correctmation.gif"` => works fine

*My Video* : `Source="pack://application:,,,/Medias/Video1.mp4"` => not working

*My Video* : `Source="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Video1.mp4"` => workis fine but I don't want this directly path

also for my video file I tried these `BuildAction`:

- Embedded
- Resource
- Content Resource

none of them work.

*XAML*:

```
 <Grid>
        <Label Content="Embeded Video :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
        <MediaElement x:Name="Embd_Video1_mp4" Margin="115,10,499,309" Stretch="Fill" Source="pack://application:,,,/Medias/Video1.mp4"/>
        
        <Label Content="Normal Path :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82"/>
        <MediaElement x:Name="Normal_Video1_mp4" Margin="115,134,444,154" Stretch="Fill" Source="Medias/Video1.mp4"/>
        
        <Label Content="Direct Path :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,345,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82"/>
        <MediaElement x:Name="Dir_Video1_mp4" Margin="115,278,331,10" Stretch="Fill" Source="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Video1.mp4"/>
        
        <Label Content="Embeded Gif Here ↓:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="452,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114"/>
        <Image Margin="452,65,30,189" Source="pack://application:,,,/Medias/1Correctmation.gif" />
    </Grid>
```

What should I do ?

**Update**:
I tried to check if has error in `MedaFailed` event , so check it out

1. `Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Medias/CorrectVideo.mp4"` error says :
   [image]

...

2. `Source="pack://application:,,,/Medias/CorrectVideo.mp4"` error says :
   [image]

***Source Code*** :
https://mega.nz/file/B1Zi2S6C#VtCk8xcdabekNIySc9-6C2yMNdV5z-qHoTCUnYl0CXA

is there any alternative for this issue ?

Comment: try: Source="/Medias/Video1.mp4" and in build type pick "Copy if Newer"

Comment: thanks for your comment , I tried with **BuildAction** => Resource   and  **Copy To Output Directory** => Copy if newer but still notworking !

Comment: mega file no more available!